# Is there some pipe operator to last argument or a way to define it in F#?

Tags: f#

I want a piping operator able to pipe as last parameter. For example, with this definitions:

```ml
let download  (uri: String) scoped  =
    use client = new HttpClient()
    task {
        let! stream = client.GetStreamAsync(uri)
        let! r = scoped stream
        return r
    }

let decompressStream stream scoped   =
    use decompressedStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress)
    task {
        let! r = scoped decompressedStream
        return r
    }

let writeToTempFile (stream: Stream) =
    let fileName = Path.GetTempFileName()
    use fileStream = File.OpenWrite(fileName)
    task {
        do! stream.CopyToAsync(fileStream)
        return fileName
    }
```

I want to be able to write this code (suppose the operator is |&> ):

```ml
let downloadAndDecompress =
    download |&> decompressStream |&> writeToTempFile
```

So I can compose functions, putting right side as last parameter (parameter scoped) of the left side of the operator. The operator should be left associative. So at the end, In my example, I would use downloadAndDecompress passing an url and I would get the temp filename with the decompressed content as result.

I'm trying with this code:

```ml
type LastPipedArg = 
    static member inline (|&>)( f: 'a1 -> 'r, lastArg: 'a1) =
        f lastArg

    static member inline (|&>)(f: 'a1 -> 'a2 -> 'r, lastArg: 'a2) =
        fun a1 -> f a1 lastArg

    static member inline (|&>)( f: 'a1 -> 'a2 -> 'a3 -> 'r, lastArg: 'a3) =
        fun a1 a2 -> f a1 a2 lastArg
        
    static member inline (|&>)(f: 'a1 -> 'a2 -> 'a3 -> 'a4-> 'r, lastArg: 'a4) =
        fun a1 a2 a3 -> f a1 a2 a3 lastArg
```

But, I cant get this to work.

So, is there some implementation of this semantics or something very similar? How can implement the custom binary piping operator?

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible to compose like this. The types just don't align (neither return types nor the signature of `scoped` in both functions).

Comment: the scopes are the same in some sense. they are continuations, that receive a parameter with the handler (like effect handler). The scoper funcion (which receive scoped as last parameter) control the lifetime of external resources and provides the handler to scoped function. With the combinator, I wish to scope from left to right, where the most scoped/internal function is the most at the right. Thats what I want to get.

Comment: @GabrielGuillermo: "So at the end, In my example, I would use downloadAndDecompress passing an url and I would get the temp filename with the decompressed content as result." Can you explain this a little more? If the end result is a function of type `url : string -> filename : Task<string>`, then what is the purpose of the two `scoped` functions and when do you supply them?

Comment: You are right. downloadAndDecompress would get the url(string) and would return the filename (string). The point about scoped is to get dynamic scoping of the external resources, a la algebraic effects. So, scoped is the continuation that will receive the handler/resource. Scoper function is agnostic about what you will do with the resource. It only manages its lifetime, like doing inversion of control, with scoped being the user of the resource and scoper being the manager of the resource. The concept is to supply the scoped arg (last arg) implicitly, using the new operator,  right to left.

Comment: The final reason is I want to try to get something like dynamic scoping with effect handlers, where the handlers would be the argument of scoped function, where the resumption part is enabled using task state machines.

Comment: Maybe somwthing is missing: when then function downloadAndDecompress terminates, there are not more effects from the code inside it, or code called by it. In this case, when the function is terminated, with or without exception, all necesary resources had been closed: the http connection and the file. The end result would be the name of the temp file. But the file is fully written and closed and that point; and the http stream is fully readen and closed.

Comment: "The concept is to supply the scoped arg (last arg) implicitly, using the new operator, right to left." The problem is that at some point, you have to **explicitly** provide the `scoped` functions, and I can't see where you intend to do that. They aren't present when you *define* `downloadAndDecompress` and they also aren't present when you *call* `downloadAndDecompress`, so exactly when do they show up in your design?

Comment: In this example, writeToTempFile passed as arg scoped for left side of second pipe. decompressStream is passed as arg scoped for left side of first pipe (function download). First pipe returns a function (name it newf) wich itself requieres arg scoped. newf is left side of second pipe and writeToTempFile is passed as arg scoped for newf.

Comment: In more complex designs, you would pass new scoped args more levels up in the call stack. But, at each level, the scoped function is the next funtion down in the stack.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand what you mean now. Will try to think of a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I think I figured this out. The operator you're describing is basically an infix version of what's usually called `flip`:

```ml
let (|&>) f a b =
    f b a
```

With that, you can define `downloadAndDecompress` as:

```ml
let downloadAndDecompress =
    download |&> (decompressStream |&> writeToTempFile)
```

The parentheses are needed because the operator is left-associative. Or you can eliminate the need for parens by using a right-associative operator instead, like this:

```ml
let (^&>) f a b =
    f b a

let downloadAndDecompress =
    download ^&> decompressStream ^&> writeToTempFile
```

Comment: Really awesome!, It's working in my example. I'm not sure why. I was thinking for different parameters count, for example writeToTempFile only recieve scoped but decompressStream  receives scoped and other parameter, I would need different overloads. I will analyze the code to understand why is working. Thanks you very much!